# Facebook Realtime Updates - get notified when users friend updates photo

Tags: facebook, real-time-updates

Using the Realtime Updates I can get notified when a user uploads a photo, but is it possible to get notified when one of their friends uploads a photo?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) you can't subscribe to changes to `User.home` (the user's news feed).  This is where you would see friends' photos, so I conclude you can't get notifications for these events.